# Reaching state N in at most n=4 steps

Tags: stochastic-processes

I was working on a question and I doubt the solution given is the right one. To simplify, consider a state space $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and an initial distribution $a^{(0)}=(1,0,0,0,0,0)$ with transition matrix P.

The question asks for the probability of reaching state 6 in at most 4 turns if we start from state 1. Their answer is given as the 6th element from $$a^{(4)}=a^{(0)}P^4$$.

I doubt this is the answer as it coincides with $P(X_4 = 6|X_{0}=1)$ which is not what we want. Could anyone help? Thanks!

I have added the actual problem where it looks for the probability of reaching the last state, 8, in at most 4 turns, starting from state 4. I am more interested in the method, but I added the actual question if people want to know it.

$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
and $a^{(0)} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: Does the transition matrix in fact allow any transitions $6 \to n$ where $n \neq 6$?

Comment: Could you include matrix $P$ so someone here could check?

Comment: Modified the question to include the original problem.